# Error with returning True or False when I enter a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know what's wrong in this code. I want this program to print the character or to show a message, for example "you didn't type only 1 character". Can you help me please ?

```
def PrintVariable(lit):
variable = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
            "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
for i in variable:
    if(i == lit):
        print("Your character is ", i)

def CheckIfLitIsNumber(lit):
    numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    for z in numbers:
        if (z == lit):
           return True
        else:
           return False

lit = (input("Give a character "))
if len(lit) == 1 and (CheckIfLitIsNumber(lit) is False):
    PrintVariable(lit)
else:
    print("You didn't give a character or you've entered a word")
```

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: Both your `for`s are not necessary - `if lit in variable:` will suffice. Furthermore, `lit.isalpha()` and `lit.isdigit()` are standard library functions so you don't need the above.

Comment: Your question is phrased wrong, It looks like your code's error is when it is a number, not a word. Are you sure it doesn't give the right message when you typed multiple characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first iteration of `for` loop in `CheckIfLitIsNumber`, if `z` is not equal to `lit`; your code is returning `False`. In other words, in your current code `for` is having no meaning as it is returning the `True`/`False` based on the comparison of `numbers[0]==lit`.

Instead you should be returning the `False` value at the completion of `for` loop. Hence, you code should be like:

```
def CheckIfLitIsNumber(lit):
    numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    for z in numbers:
        if (z == lit):
           return True
    else:
        return False
    # ^   ^  please note the indentation
```

Also note that the `input()` in Python always returns `str`. For changing it to `int` type, you'll have to type-cast it. Hence, before passing the value to `CheckIfLitIsNumber`, only then you'll be able to perform integer comparison. Please refer: [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

---

However, you do not need both of these functions. You may get the same result via just doing:

```
import string
variable = string.lowercase  # string of all the lowercase characters

lit = input("Give a character ")

#                          v check presence of `lit` in `variable` string
if len(lit) == 1  and lit in variable:  
    print("Your character is ", lit)
else:
    print("You didn't give a character or you've entered a word")
```

It is even better to change your `if` condition to:

```
#                         v checks whether number is alphabet or not
if len(lit) == 1  and lit.isalpha():
```

Comment: Also, if he wants to use the CheckifLitIsNumber and compare to a list of integers, he needs to `CheckIfLitIsNumber(int(lit))`. `input()` returns a string in Python3.

Comment: `not lit.isdigit()` should suffice as you'd need a `try/except` statement for the case when it is a number.

Comment: Yes. I missed that. @Andrei please see the comment mentioned by TemporalWolf and Steven. For details, you may refer: [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error when doing

```
def CheckIfLitIsNumber(lit):
    numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    for z in numbers:
        if (z == lit):
           return True
    else:
        return False
```

Since `numbers` is an `int array`, comparing that to `lit`, a `string`, will always return false. For example:

```
>>> "1" == 1
False
```

Instead, what you would want to do is `catch` a `TypeError`, like so:

**Do NOT use this code, look below to see what to use instead.**

```
def CheckIfLitIsNumber(lit):
    try:
        return isinstance(int(lit), int)
    Except TypeError:
        return false
```

In this example, if `lit` is actually a string, running `int(lit)` will give a `TypeError`, which is subsequently `caught` and `return false` is run instead.
Though this would work, it would be much simpler just to use `lit.isdigit()`, like this:

```
def CheckIfLitIsNumber(lit):
    return not lit.isdigit()
```